# Selecting the latest entry in a single MYSQL column and assigning it to a php variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a 4 column mysql table, the leftmost being the autoincrement column and I'd like to get the variable value for a column called `extra` for the highest auto increment value.  I believe the SQL query will be:

`Select extra FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"`

```
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypass', 'mydb');    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT extra FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
    $variablevalue = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch the data 
    echo "The variable is converted to a string and its value is $variablevalue.";
    // set parameters and execute
```

When  try to `echo "The variable is converted to a string and its value is $variablevalue."` I see: `The variable is converted to a string and its value is Array` I am expecting to see an integer here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php and note that it says:  _"Returns an associative array..."_ so it's not clear why you expected it to say anything other than `Array` there? Or did you not read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetch_assoc()` function returns an associative array so you would access the value by the name of the column:

`$variablevalue['extra']`;